# Automapper -> map named properties of object to an array property

Tags: c#, automapper

So i have an object that has an array and i need to map properties of another object to this array. In Automapper 5 i used to do this using "ResolveUsing" but after updating automapper this does not work. What i did before was:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Array, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(o =>
                {
                    return new[] {
                        new Arra() { Key = "Key", Value = o.Value },
                        new Arra() { Key = "Key2", Value = o.Value2 }
                    };
                }));
```

In the upgrade guide they mention that ResolveUsing is no longer used: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/8.0-Upgrade-Guide.html after reading this I actually have no clue how to fix this though.

All searches guide me to issues where people try to map array -> named properties while mine is the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you i believe-

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Array, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => new[] {
                        new Arra() { Key = "Key", Value = o.Value },
                        new Arra() { Key = "Key2", Value = o.Value2 }
                    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with MapFrom instead of Resolve using ?

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Array, opt => opt.MapFrom(o => new[] {
                    new Arra() { Key = "Key", Value = o.Value },
                    new Arra() { Key = "Key2", Value = o.Value2 }
            }));
```